# Double bar chart creation

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, data-visualization

I want to create a bar chart like this:

[image]

There are two chart bars one below the other, the first one grows upwards while the second one grows downwards.
They have different scales and data.

This is what I created:

```
var doublebarSvg1 = d3.select('#doublebar')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'doublebarSvg1')
    .attr('width', 700)
    .attr('height', 400);

var doublebarSvg2 = d3.select('#doublebar')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'doublebarSvg2')
    .attr('width', 700)
    .attr('height', 400);

var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 50};

var width = doublebarSvg1.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = doublebarSvg1.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.1)
    .domain(years);

var y1 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0])
    .domain([0, 100]);

var y2 = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .rangeRound([height, 0])
    .domain([813, 0.1]); // max value 812.05 but domain is [0, 100000]

var doublebarSvgG1 = doublebarSvg1.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');
var doublebarSvgG2 = doublebarSvg2.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Tooltip.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var svgTip = doublebarSvg1.append('svg').attr('id', 'tooltip');

var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-5, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        return '<div><span>Country:</span> <span style=\'color:white\'>' + d.country + '</span></div>' +
                 '<div><span>Perc:</span> <span style=\'color:white\'>' + d.perc + '%</span></div>' +
                 '<div><span>Rate:</span> <span style=\'color:white\'>' + d.rate + '%</span></div>';
    });
svgTip.call(tip);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Draw a single double bar
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
makeDoublebar1();

function makeDoublebar1() {
    // define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x); 
    var yAxis1 = d3.axisLeft(y1);

    // create x axis
    doublebarSvgG1.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')') 
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll('text')  
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('dx', '-.8em')
        .attr('dy', '.15em')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-65)');

    // create y axis
    doublebarSvgG1.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .call(yAxis1)
        .append('text')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('y', 6)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .style('text-anchor', 'end');

    // create bar rect
    doublebarSvgG1.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(testData1) //.data(covFiltered)
        .enter().append('rect')
        .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return x(d.year); 
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) { 
            if(isNaN(d.perc)) {
                d.perc = 0;
            }
            return y1(d.perc); 
        })
        .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', function(d) { 
            if(isNaN(d.perc)) {
                d.perc = 0;
            }
            return height - y1(d.perc); 
        })
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {
            d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'darkblue');
            tip.show(d);
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(d) {
            d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'steelblue');
            tip.hide(d);
        });
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Draw a single double bar
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
makeDoublebar2();

function makeDoublebar2() {
    // define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x); 
    var yAxis2 = d3.axisLeft(y2);

    // create x axis
    doublebarSvgG2.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)') 
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll('text')  
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('dx', '-.8em')
        .attr('dy', '.15em')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-65)');

    // create y axis
    doublebarSvgG2.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .call(yAxis2)
        .append('text')
        .style('text-anchor', 'end');

    // create bar rect
    doublebarSvgG2.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(testData2)
        .enter().append('rect')
        .attr('fill', 'tomato')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('x', function(d) { // left start point
            return x(d.year); 
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) { // top start point
            if(isNaN(d.rate)) {
                d.rate = 0;
            }
            return 0; 
        })
        .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', function(d) { 
            if(isNaN(d.rate)) {
                d.perc = 0;
            }
            return y2(d.rate); 
        })
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {
            d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'red');
            tip.show(d);
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(d) {
            d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'tomato');
            tip.hide(d);
        });
}
```

[**PLUNKER here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/So6rReoSFjPpC4d6ohsT?p=preview).

There are some problem:

1. if I replace `.axis {display: initial;}` with `.axis {display: none;}`, all the axis disappear but I want the horizontal line between the two chart
2. I would like there to be only one tooltip, which when the user hovers over any bar, comes out with a tooltip that shows both `perc` and `rate` value.

And, more importantly, is this the smartest way to create a chart like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double bar chart in d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252053/double-bar-chart-in-d3)

Comment: This is clearly not a duplicate. In that first question OP is just asking how to create the double bar chart, which is too broad (that close vote is mine, btw). In this one OP has an actually working code and they're asking about specific issues. Very different.

Comment: @Buster Sorry for the mess in my answer, I wrote *"yes"* for *"is this the smartest way to create a chart like that?"*, because in my mind I read *"is there a smarter way..."*. So, the answer is **no**! Feel free to ask about this at Code Review, but please read [their instructions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks, I create [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194419/d3js-create-a-double-bar-chart) on Code Review.

Comment: @Buster I asked you to read their instructions first! Your question has 1 downvote already... You should not mention the small multiples, which is another feature that doesn't exist in the code. You should just show your code and ask for a review. Also, even linking the plunker, put the *whole code* in the question: this is unacceptable here, but it's the standard there.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Ok, I deleted the part on small multiples (I thought it was relevant in order to understand how the code organization would be useful). Ah, I had read the instructions before posting. Anyway, it does not matter, it's a my mistake.

Comment: @Buster It's better now! I'll have a look at it sometime tonight. Answers at CR take a long time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the axis, since you want to keep the horizontal line, just hide the ticks and the texts:

```
.x.axis text,.x.axis line {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

The tooltip problem is a bit more complex. The issue is that you're binding different data arrays to each set of bars.

Because of that, the best idea is finding the desired object in each array when you hover over a given year and getting the respective properties:

```
var thisPerc = testData1.find(function(e){return e.year === d.year}).perc;
var thisRate = testData2.find(function(e){return e.year === d.year}).rate;
```

Then you use those properties for setting the tooltip's text.

Here is the updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tfB4TpkETgzp5GF1677p?p=preview

Finally, for your last question (*"And, more importantly, is this the smartest way to create a chart like that?"*), the answer is **no**. There are a lot of things that can (and must) be changed here, but this involves a lot of refactoring and it's arguably off topic at Stack Overflow. However, this is an adequate question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). But please [read their docs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first for keeping your question on topic, asking there is not the same as asking here.